# Get a value from a variable of a class, via reflection and then use methods of a value

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to get a value from a variable of a class via reflection way. For example, I have the `Car` class and it has engine property. Also, in the `Engine` class, I override the `toString()` method and defined one more `hello()` method.

And then when I try to get a value via

`getDeclaredField()` method, seems like I get a correct value of `Engine` instance, but for some reasons I can't call method `hello()` on it.

**Car** class

```java
public class Car {
    final Engine engine = new Engine();
}
```

**Engine** class

```java
public class Engine {

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Engine";
    }
}
```

**Main** class

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Field field = Car.class.getDeclaredField("engine");
            Object value = field.get(new Car());

            // It's print Engine as expected
            System.out.println(value);

            // But I can't call hello() method
            // value.hello()

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the `hello()` method, first verify that your `value` is an instance of `Engine` (using `instanceof`) and then ***cast*** `value` to an `Engine`. Like,

```
// Check type, cast instance and call hello() method
if (value instanceof Engine) {
    ((Engine) value).hello();
}
```

which you can also write like

```
if (value instanceof Engine) {
    Engine.class.cast(value).hello();
}
```

it's also common to save the `Class` reference and use it instead of hardcoding the particular `Class` you are working with; for example,

```
Class<? extends Engine> cls = Engine.class
// ...
if (cls.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
    cls.cast(value).hello();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Elliott! it works like a charm! my thoughts were that when we getting value from the property, it's already has a correct type and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to call

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

before you try to access it.
Though that may be only for private fields, see @Elliott.Frisch reply

Comment: Hm, it needed only for `private` properties, isn't?